# EF 6 throws error in web api for few request ( Underlying provider failed to open )

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a web app service which handles webhooks from the Facebook .

I get approximately 110 request per minute and Im inserting the request body into a table and processing it .  As I get too many requests I getting The following error.

**The underlying provider failed on Open. Inner Exception: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction  error for half of the request** .

Its not a problem with connection as only half of the requests getting this error other requests are processed properly . 
I have enabled the Pooling and set the MAx pool size to 200 in the connection string. I also enabled the DTC options in the server .

My code is like below.

```
using(var context = new DBEntities())
{
    context.Table.Add(data);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In server also I have set the parallel connection as unlimited .

When I run the `Sp_who2` it shows 64 connections among only 12 are EntityFramework programe.

I don't know why after enabling the Connection pooling also EF has max connection of 12.

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Max Pool Size=200;Pooling:True;
```

Please somebody help me to identify the issue.

Comment: Is it an `async` action method?

Comment: its not an async method

Comment: And what do you mean by `parallel connection as unlimited`? SQL server? If so, that's against all recommendations.

Comment: In SqL Server Properties under Connection section I set 0 for Maximum number of concurrent connections

Comment: Writing data one row at a time isn't a great idea with high volume inserts (although 2 per second should be OK). If you can, would suggest that you look at buffering data for a few seconds at a time and write a bunch of rows at a time. At higher volumes still, you'll likely need to change out of Entity Framework down to ADO or even something like [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @StuartLC ,  you mean that I cant use EF 6 for a web site which has 100 active users parallely ?

Comment: @mjwills it thorws error from context.SaveChanges() line. Error that is logged  " The underlying provider failed on Open. Inner Excpetion  : The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction."

Comment: Please add that detail to your post not in comments @Gowtham .

Comment: @Gowtham it isn't the number of concurrent users which worries me, it's the fact that it's a FaceBook webhook. Although FB will likely be able to throttle, see if there is a set-based callback (i.e multiple updates in one payload), and you should then try and process this set in one operation.

Comment: @StuartLC Yes , the FB request has multiple updates in a payload , I wrote the code to handle it . The multiple updates in a single request are also getting processed successfully at times .  I can change the code like you suggested by saving the response in blob storage and process it by batches and store it in DB using SQLBulkCopy .but I'm worried that in future when concurrent users use my website other tables( login , account,useractivity..etc ) shouldn't throw error like this .